# Find the radius of convergence for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^n}{3^n+4^n}z^n$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, limits

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^n}{3^n+4^n}z^n$$

What I've done is try to evaluate the expression sans $z^n$ with the root test.

$$\sqrt[n]{\frac{2^n}{3^n+4^n}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt[n]{3^n+4^n}}$$

But I'm stuck with the denominator, how does one evaluate such expressions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that $4^n+3^n=4^n\cdot(1+(3/4)^n)$.

Comment: Wow, that's so obvious! Can't believe I missed it. Thanks